# Customize numbering figures 1, 2.1, 2.2, 3, 4 with AMS and hyperref

Tags: floats, numbering, counters

Ordinarily I use amsart and hyperref and number figures 1, 2, 3, 4. In some situations, I need to split a figure into multiple parts so the parts can each fit on a page, and then I want to sub-number the parts, e.g. 2.1, 2.2, 2.3. What is a good way to do this?  The solutions I've seen in Stackexchange don't work for me; either the numbers on the figures aren't correct or I get the message

> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

Answer (score 1):

You could use subfigures and `\ContinuedFloat`, but switching back and forth with normal subfigures could get messy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subgroup}{Figure~#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=subgroup,labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \caption{First Part}\label{one}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \caption{Second part}\label{two}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{Normal Caption}\label{three}
\end{figure}

Links to \ref{one}. \ref{two} and \ref{three}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method that works for me is this:

Put this just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\newcounter{figuregroup}
```

At the beginning of a "figure group", insert:

```
\global\let\thefiguresave=\thefigure
\global\let\theHfiguresave=\theHfigure
\numberwithin{figure}{figuregroup}
\addtocounter{figure}{1}
\setcounter{figuregroup}{\value{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
```

Then have a sequence of `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`.

At the end of the "figure group", insert:

```
\global\let\thefigure=\thefiguresave
\global\let\theHfigure=\theHfiguresave
\setcounter{figure}{\value{figuregroup}}
```

As far as I can tell, part of my problems come from using `hyperref`, which is taken care of here.  If you're using one of the AMS styles *without* hyperref, you likely have to remove the lines that contain `\theH...`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be made somewhat nicer by putting this before `\begin{document}`:

```
\newenvironment{figuregroup}{%
  \global\let\thefiguresave=\thefigure
  \global\let\theHfiguresave=\theHfigure
  \numberwithin{figure}{figuregroup}
  \addtocounter{figure}{1}
  \setcounter{figuregroup}{\value{figure}}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
}{%
  \global\let\thefigure=\thefiguresave
  \global\let\theHfigure=\theHfiguresave
  \setcounter{figure}{\value{figuregroup}}
}
```

And then structuring the figure group this way:

```
\begin{figuregroup}

\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}

...

\end{figuregroup}
```